# Doubling of the letter 'p' when compounding two word

Tags: compound-words

I am trying to name a little computer program I wrote.

I would like to name it *mapit* as a compound of map and it.

I was wondering if it should rather be *mappit*, with the 'p' doubled as in mapping.

I know mapping is not a compound word, but I couldn't think of an example of a compound word where the first word ends with 'p'.

Comment: When you're coining your own names for things, you can spell them anyhow you like; *mappit* is not going to be mispronounced, and people will figure out where it comes from.

Comment: Doubling the ending consonant is often done to eliminate confusion about the pronunciation.

Comment: 'Mapppit' is equally 'acceptable' (though booty being in the eye of the buyer, I wouldn't recommend it).

Comment: Note that WhatsApp has a double 'p'...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Names don't have to follow all the rules of grammar, but "Mappit" is clearly the better choice. "Mappit" simply looks much better, so it is easier to pronounce correctly. "Mapit" would likely often be mispronounced may-pit.

However, "Mappit" [has already been used by a wall decor company](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07451RY77).

Comment: Good catch on the "wall decor company". That would seem to be  deal-breaker.

Comment: Thanks!, the wall decor company would not be a problem as this will not be a publicly available product but an internally used tool